# Get main account photo

Tags: android, contacts, google-account

I am creating an app and I have a photo for the user and I would like to automatically pull it. I am not really sure how to do this or what would even be the best way to do this.

Is there a way to pull the google account photo? This might not even be the best way to go considering that plenty of people world wide may not have a google account at all.

Is there a default contact for the user of the phone in the ContactProvider and if so how would I go about getting it and the photo it has. Sorry I don't have any code, I just don't know where to start and a suggestion or a link might point me in the right direction.

Okay code that I tried

```
String[] mProjection = new String[]
            {
            Profile._ID,
            Profile.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
            Profile.LOOKUP_KEY,
            Profile.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI
            };

    // Retrieves the profile from the Contacts Provider
    Cursor mProfileCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            Profile.CONTENT_URI,
            mProjection ,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    try {
         if (mProfileCursor.moveToFirst()) {
             byte[] data = mProfileCursor.getBlob(0); //error on this line
             if (data != null) {
                 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                 imageBit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
             }
         }
     } finally {
         mProfileCursor.close();
     }
```

I keep getting an error on the noted line:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): INTEGER data in nativeGetBlob

Edit 2: so I changed the 0 to a 3 to get the profile photo it fixed my one error but now the imageBit that I get from decoding the stream is null. The byte[] however is not so I don't know what the issue is converting the byte[] to an bitmap

Comment: 0 will be the _ID, try 3. And pretty sure it will not return a blob but an URI so you could use MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap with the content resolver and this uri.

Comment: yup that seems to be making progress, it fixed my one error but now the imageBit is now that I get from decoding the stream is null. The byte[] however is not so I don't know what the issue is converting the byte[] to an bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `ContactsContract.Contacts` you can found a row dedicated to the Phone owner.

Remember to add `READ_PROFILE` permission to your application.

```
// Sets the columns to retrieve for the user profile
mProjection = new String[]
    {
        Profile.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI
    };

// Retrieves the profile from the Contacts Provider
mProfileCursor =
        getContentResolver().query(
                Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                mProjection ,
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

Then use `mProfileCursor` to get the data and show it.

More info, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#UserProfile).

Comment: will give it a shot and report back

Comment: so I tried it but I seem to be having issues getting the photo data from the cursor